# Печать части html страницы

Tags: html, html5, печать

Как сделать, чтобы при выводе на печать, часть html страницы не отображалась.

Допустим:

```
Строка №1

Строка №2

Кнопка Печатать
```

Как сделать так, чтобы строки вывелись на печать, а сама кнопка нет.

Вывод на печать сейчас делаю вот таким образом:

```
<input type="submit" value="Печатать" class="btn btn-default" 
onClick="window.print()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно [перенастроить всё через CSS](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media) (предварительно добавив ID или класс кнопке печати):

```
/* Обычные стили */
body { ... }
.line { ... }

.print-button {cursor: pointer; ...}

/* Стили для печати */
@media print {
    .print-button {display: none;} /* <-- */

    .line {color: black; ...}
    ...
}
```